# How to send SonarLint analysis results to the SonarQube server from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sonarlint

Is it possible to send plugin analysis results to the SonarQube server from Visual Studio?

I work in connected mode, click Update from TeamExplorer->SonarQube-Connections. But server itself is not updated with the results.
[image]

I have to do some CLI stuff I've found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/28/quickstart-analyzing-net-projects-with-sonarqube-msbuild-or-visual-studio-online-and-third-party-analyzers-stylecop-resharper/

in order to update the server

```
path=%path%;C:\Sq\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.1

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin /n:Backlogmaps /v:1.0 /k:blm

Msbuild

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end
```

Answer (score 8):

SonarLint cannot push analysis results to SonarQube. As you already found, you need to use the [command line scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) or setup our [Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) or [TFS extensions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) on your CI server.

SonarLint for Visual Studio does exactly two things:

- Transparently enables the SonarC# analyzers for any supported project in Visual Studio, helping you to check your code before committing.
- Allows the project owner to connect a project to a SonarQube server, which will automatically enforce the same rules for all developers who work on that project. The `Update` command in the context menu downloads the quality profile from SonarQube and updates the Visual Studio project settings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Valeri, make sense. So "update" button is synchronizing settings and SonarQube should be updated after pushing the code (not from a dev machine).

Comment: How should I check my code in vs 2017 before committing though?  Just run analyzer and check "Error List" window or there is a more advanced window with metrics/technical debts/.etc. (like in SonarQube dashboard) ?

Comment: Update button downloads the rule settings (e.g. quality profile) from SonarQube and updates the project. Not the other way around. And yes, you should check the error window while coding.